# Dynamically name dataframes, created by split function

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe like this

```
q1   q2  q3
A    12  15
A    17  29
A    10  13
B    33  56
B    46  35
B    25  64
```

and I want to split it to different dataframes, which I do with

```
split(df1, df1$q1)
```

I get that part, but I want to make calculations on each of newly created dataframes. How do I name and save those splitted parts to a new dataframes?

Comment: I would suggest to keep it in a list instead of creating new objects On the `list`, you can do `lapply(lst1, yourfunction)`

Comment: See gregor's answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) for some tips.